# How to specify additional source folders for GWT project with Google Eclipse plugin?

Tags: gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

My GWT project has all code in the `src` folder. But now I have some additional generated code which goes into a new `generated` folder. I have configured my Eclipse to use this additional folder, which works fine. But when I start the GWT server, the generated code is not available for the GWT client.

On my older projects (without Google Plugin), I was starting GWT with a custom Eclipse launcher configuration. There I could specify additional source folders by adding an additional `<runtimeClasspathEntry>` to the launcher XML file.

Additional source paths are also allowed for `com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler` in Ant.

But how to specify additional source folders when using the Google Eclipse Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GPE doesn't automatically update the launch configuration, you can still update it yourself, adding the `generated` folder to the classpath.

Comment: Ok, this works. Problem is, this classpath is saved only in my personal Eclipse workspace. All other developers would have to do the same. Is it possible to save this additional classpath in the project settings or in some project file which can be commited?

Comment: @Witek yes you can commit the class path file if it contains relative path.

Comment: @Braj In this case it's not the project's `.classpath` but rather the launch configuration. That said, the answer is similar: you can export/save the launch configuration into a file; just make sure it only contains relative paths; but beware of end-of-lines when you have people on Windows and others on Linux or OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to add it in source as shown below to add it in build path of the project.

click on `Add Folder...` to add the generated folder on build path.

If it doesn't work the go to -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder...

---

Add entries in your `gwt.xml` to make it available for client side code as shown below

```
<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
<!-- path related to root of GWT project similar to client and shared folder-->
<source path='generated_folder' />
```

[image]

Comment: In my question I stated that I have already configured Eclipse to use the additional folder. Which works perfectly for compiling. But GWT (the client side) still does not use the additional source path.

Comment: Have you tried with `<source path='generated_folder' />`

Comment: where is generated_folder placed in your project?

Comment: In my project folder I have src and the new generated folder side by side. <source> in gwt.xml does not allow to specify new source folders. It's only for packages within the somewhere else specified source folders.